# How do I distribute values in single column to several columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a pandas dataframe (using PyCharm) with values:

```
Colour
-----
Red
Green
Green
Blue
Red
```

But I would want to split it up to several columns with headings "Red", "Green", "Blue" and then have the values set to 'yes' or 'no'.

```
Red  Blue Green
--------------
Yes  No  No
No   No  Yes
No   No  Yes
No   Yes No
Yes  No  No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df.Colour.str.get_dummies().replace({1:'Yes', 0:'No'})

   Blue Green Red
0   No    No  Yes
1   No   Yes   No
2   No   Yes   No
3  Yes    No   No
4   No    No  Yes
```

Comment: Did this help @limpan? Remember to accept if so, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Colour': ['Red', 'Green', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red']})
df
    Colour
0   Red
1   Green
2   Green
3   Blue
4   Red

pd.get_dummies(df['Colour']).replace({0:'No', 1:'Yes'})
     Blue            Green  Red
0     No              No    Yes
1     No              Yes   No
2     No              Yes   No
3     Yes             No    No
4     No              No    Yes
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have a long column with colors, containing 3000 values? In my question I just described the format of the data.

Comment: Yes, This solution would still work and is also efficient. Did you find any problem?

Comment: What do i put in instead of the values within the hard brackets that you provided in your answer (['Red', 'Green', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red'])?

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you put in what?